# How to load a static locale json for i18n translation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to add a fallback local json, if the language API fails.In the i18n.js file of my react native app, i have added two path : one will fetch from API and another fetches local JSON translation. But i could not load the local translation as the react native is not accepting public folder in which i have placed my translations.

This is the i18n.js file.

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import Backend from 'i18next-chained-backend';
import { getLocales } from 'react-native-localize';
import Axios from "axios";
import { API_BASE_URL } from '../../config';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: getLocales()[0].languageCode,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    backend: {
      backends: [
        HttpApi,
        HttpApi
      ],
      backendOptions: [
        {
          loadPath: `${API_BASE_URL}/xyzzzzzzz/{{lng}}`,
          parse: (data) => {
            return data
          },
          request: (options, url, payload, callback) => {
            Axios.post(url, {
              domain: `${API_BASE_URL}`
            })
              .then((res) => {
                callback(null, res);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                callback(err, null);
              });
          },
        },
        {
          loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json'
        }
      ]
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

The translations are in the root/*public/locales/en/translation.json*

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a local http server running in your react-native app... so you can't use the HttpApi backend for the local translations.

Here you can find an example with local caching: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/caching#react-native-caching-with-asyncstorage

Alternatively, you can define your local translations via resources option: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/react-native/App.js#L20
https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-on-init
and if you have just a partial set of translations locally, you can try with the `partialBundledLanguages` option: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I tried adding resources via option like you mentioned, but if i do that, then when the API request response comes, it is not taking language from it.
I even added the option partialBundledLanguages: true, either it takes from resources object or backend, not from both. So that i can write a fallback incase the API fails.